# Move line in Joe's Own Editor

Tags: joe

Is there a way to move a line up and down in the [joe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe%27s_Own_Editor) editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one, at least in the joe configuration. Here's a pair of macros that I wrote. The up macro is a fairly straightforward cut-and-paste; it does nothing when called on the first line. The down macro is more complex because it has to behave a bit differently when called on the next-to-last line (this may just be because I'm not good at writing joe macros); when called on the last incomplete line, it inserts a newline before. I bind them to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd>.

```
:main
if,"line!=1",then,home,dellin,uparw,yank,uparw,endif ^K .ku  Move current line up
if,"line<lines-1",then,home,dellin,dnarw,yank,uparw,elsif,"line==lines",then,bol,rtn,else,bol,deleol,dnarw,yank,deleol,uparw,yank,endif ^K .kd  Move current line down
```

In the jmacs configuration, there is a macro to transpose two lines:

```
psh,if,"arg>=0",then,
  uparw,bol,markb,dnarw,markk,dnarw,
  blkmove,dnarw,
else,
  bol,markk,uparw,markb,uparw,blkmove,
  dnarw,
endif   ^X ^T                   Transpose lines
```

I'll let a joe expert comment on the respective merits of the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I have to save the macro? is there any file for that?

Comment: @SimonWarta This goes into your `~/.joerc`.

Comment: After installing the macro, I cannot type anything in any file with joe anymore. Even Ctrl+C is disabled, to I cannot close the editor :(

Comment: @SimonWarta It works for me. Does it help if you add `:include /etc/joe/joerc` (or whatever the path to the system `joerc` is) as the first line of `.joerc`, with no indent? Did you have a `.joerc` before?

Comment: Okay, thanks. There was no `~/.joerc` before, so my `~/.joerc` did overwrite the default config. `:include /etc/joe/joerc` helped. But I still can not move lines. When I press `CTRG+K` together followed by an `↑`, a capital "A" is inserted.

Comment: @SimonWarta Does the arrow key normally work in Joe? It looks like your environment is misconfigured and the arrow key doesn't send the key sequence that Joe expects. Replacing `^K .ku` by `^K ^[ O A` or `^K ^[ [ A`, and with `B` instead of `A` for `.kd`, should work around the problem.

Comment: The second version works. Is my `.ku` not defined? `cat -n /etc/joe/joerc | grep "\.ku"` gives me four lines containing `.ku Up`, `uparw .ku Go up`, `uparw,eol .ku Go up` and `uparwmenu .ku`

Comment: @SimonWarta `ku` is the [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) entry indicating the escape sequence sent by the Up key. It isn't defined in the `joerc`. Figuring out why the value is wrong would be a topic for a separate question, with details about what terminal emulator you're using, on what distribution.